# GetOpenFileName fails in 64 bit, but works in 32Bit?

Tags: windows, winapi, 64-bit, openfiledialog

I have the following code, I use to Open a File Open Dialog using Win32 API. It works fine in 32bit, but fails when I use in a 64bit (In a DLL). What am I doing wrong?

```
 char Filestring[256];
Filter = "OBJ files\0*.obj\0\0";
char* returnstring = NULL;



OPENFILENAME opf;
opf.hwndOwner = mainHWND;
opf.lpstrFilter = Filter;
opf.lpstrCustomFilter = 0;
opf.nMaxCustFilter = 0L;
opf.nFilterIndex = 1L;
opf.lpstrFile = Filestring;
opf.lpstrFile[0] = '\0';
opf.nMaxFile = 256;
opf.lpstrFileTitle = 0;
opf.nMaxFileTitle=50;
opf.lpstrInitialDir = Path;
opf.lpstrTitle = "Open Obj File";
opf.nFileOffset = 0;
opf.nFileExtension = 0;
opf.lpstrDefExt = "*.*";
opf.lpfnHook = NULL;
opf.lCustData = 0;
opf.Flags = (OFN_PATHMUSTEXIST | OFN_OVERWRITEPROMPT) & ~OFN_ALLOWMULTISELECT;
opf.lStructSize = sizeof(OPENFILENAME);

if(GetOpenFileName(&opf))
{
    returnstring = opf.lpstrFile;
    if (returnstring) {
        result = returnstring;
    }

}
```

EDIT: By failing, I meant that the Open File Dialog doesn't show up. The code still returns zero without any errors.

EDIT 2: I have called CommDlgExtendedError() and it returned 1. From the MSDN reference, does it mean the dialog has invalid  lStructSize? I have checked the `sizeof(OPENFILENAME)` and it returned 140 bytes.

UPDATE: In my Project Settings, Under Code Generation the "Struct Member Alignment" is set to 4 Bytes(/Zp4). I changed this to default and it magically worked. Look for the answers and their comments below for more information.

Comment: Are you by chance calling the `Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection` function (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365743.aspx) first?

Comment: I don't think so. There is no such call in the whole project.

Comment: Can you give us any more context? What kind of a project is this? Where are you using the DLL? Is it *compiled* to 64-bit, or are you just running a 32-bit DLL on a 64-bit version of Windows?

Comment: Hello, I am using Windows 7 64bit, and the Code works fine in a compiled 32Bit DLL, but doesn't work with a compiled 64 Bit DLL. The DLL is a plugin for another host application. If it helps, I'm compiling both of them in (/MT) static.

Comment: You state "it fails" but things don't just fail, they report errors. Please get in the habit of investigating what those errors are and including them in full when you post.

Comment: Actually, I did try to get the errors, if any. But GetOpenFileName returns zero. But I don't see any File Open Dialog. I don't know if I can get any other sort of error messages. Thanks.

Comment: Also, I made sure that the mainHWND is a valid one. Other modal windows work fine when I use that parent HWND.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You aren't initialising `lpTemplateName` and so it contains random stack noise. This in turn will lead to 'hInstance` being references which also contains stack noise.

When calling a function like this you should first of all zero out the struct and only fill in the fields that are non-zero. Something like this:

```
OPENFILENAME opf={0};
opf.lStructSize = sizeof(OPENFILENAME);
opf.hwndOwner = mainHWND;
opf.lpstrFilter = Filter;
opf.nFilterIndex = 1L;
opf.lpstrFile = Filestring;
opf.lpstrFile[0] = '\0';
opf.nMaxFile = 256;
opf.lpstrInitialDir = Path;
opf.lpstrTitle = "Open Obj File";
opf.lpstrDefExt = "*.*";
opf.Flags = OFN_PATHMUSTEXIST | OFN_OVERWRITEPROMPT;
```

There was no need to exclude `OFN_ALLOWMULTISELECT` explicitly since you were not including it in the first place!

**EDIT**

You state in a comment that this doesn't work. Calling `CommDlgExtendedError` is a good idea and should tell you why it fails.

You could also try to run the minimal possible `GetOpenFileName` which is this:

```
char Filestring[MAX_PATH] = "\0";
OPENFILENAME opf={0};
opf.lStructSize = sizeof(OPENFILENAME);
opf.lpstrFile = Filestring;
opf.nMaxFile = MAX_PATH;
GetOpenFileName(&opf);
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. I tried doing that, but still have the same issue. The code returns zero, but I don't see any Dialog.

Comment: Yeah, this is probably right (I don't tend to actually *read* walls of code in a question), but it doesn't explain why it works for a 32-bit process and not for a 64-bit one.

Comment: @Cody Passing random unitialized stack noise could explain it.

Comment: Hello I have called CommDlgExtendedError() and it returned 1. From the MSDN reference, does it mean the dialog has invalid  lStructSize?

Comment: @gutsblow The `OPENFILENAME` struct has two versions (see MSDN). Which one are you using?

Comment: @gutsblow valid values for `lStructSize` on 64 bit Windows are 136 and 152, depending on the value of `_WIN32_WINNT`. What do you have for `lStructSize`?

Comment: I believe I am using the ANSII version (if thats what you mean). Also, the `lStructSuze` is sizeof(OPENFILENAME) which returns 140 bytes. I have tried changing the value to 136 & 152, but both return error '2' from CommDlgExtendedError(). Not sure what's going on.

Comment: Also, I am using the minimal possible `GetOpenFileName` as described in this post.

Comment: @gutsblow I'm sure you have a problem with your include files or your definitions. It should be one of the sizes I said. If sizeof gives 140 then your struct definition is broken. I'd guess it is not packing it for some reason, but that's a guess.

Comment: Yes, I think you are right. Something wrong with my project. I have created a vanilla x64 console project and it returns 152 bytes as the `sizeof(OPENFILENAME)`. I hate when this happens.

Comment: @gutsblow *Live by the macro, die by the macro*. That's my motto for C/C++ and why I do my level best to avoid using them!

Comment: Strangely, OPENFILENAME_SIZE_VERSION_400A also reports 140 bytes in the project. I guess its the same.

Comment: I agree. But to be honest, I don't have any weird Macros in the Project, except for the default set that come with the Project. I will look into it. Thanks again!

Comment: @gutsblow I didn't mean you personally, or your project, that swipe was aimed at C/C++ and the Windows header files.

Comment: Ok. I think I have found the issue. In my Project Settings, Under Code Generation the "Struct Member Alignment" is set to 4 Bytes(/Zp4). I changed this to default and it magically worked. Not sure, what exactly it means though.

Comment: @gutsblow that controls how structs are aligned and what packing they use. Have a read of the Wikipedia article if you aren't familiar with these terms: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment

Comment: Ah! Thanks I'll look into it. Once again, thank you for all your support.

Comment: @gutsblow You know you can up-vote as well as accept. I think that both your answers deserve at least that.

Answer (score 3):

I have the very same  problem and a partial solution :
+ the simple following simple example (proposed abobe) was not working in x64 mode.
+ I changed the complie option "struct Member Alignment" from 1byte /Zp1 to default which solved this problem (by introducing others !!!)

char Filestring[MAX_PATH] = "\0"; 
OPENFILENAME opf={0}; 
opf.lStructSize = sizeof(OPENFILENAME); 
opf.lpstrFile = Filestring; 
opf.nMaxFile = MAX_PATH; 
GetOpenFileName(&opf);

Answer (score 2):

To find out more you should call [CommDlgExtendedError](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646916%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get the error code what went wrong. Besides this I would initialize all member of the struct to 0 with

```
ZeroMemory(&opf, sizeof(opf));
```

Since the file open dialog is in reality a COM component it could be worth to check out if your thread apartment state is different under 64 bit.

```
if( RPC_E_CHANGED_MODE == CoInitialize(NULL) )
   ASSERT(FALSE); // MTA Apartment found
CoUnitialize()
```

Yours,
  Alois Kraus

Comment: `OPENFILENAME opf={0}` is equivalent to `ZeroMemory`. +1 for suggesting CommDlgExtendedError.

Comment: I don't believe COM is relevant here. `GetOpenFileName` is not a COM interface and dates back to Windows 3.1 if I recall correctly! Anyway, I believe that modern versions are indeed implemented in COM but if you go in through `GetOpenFileName`, Windows starts up lots of other threads and runs the COM out of those threads. It has to handle the COM initialization for you since `GetOpenFileName` was originally intended to be called without requiring COM init.

Comment: Hello I have called CommDlgExtendedError() and it returned 1. From the MSDN reference, does it mean the dialog has invalid  lStructSize?

Comment: Although it should not matter you can try to do ofn.lStructSize = sizeof(ofn);
Besides this I would try if the example code http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646829%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#open_file does show the same problem. If you have the same problem with the sample code then it could be that under 64 bit you have some memory corruption ongoing.

Comment: He has done `ofn.lStructSize = sizeof(ofn);` but the problem is that this sets it to 140 when it should be 136.

Answer (score 1):

As a note in Microsoft Office 2010 64-bit we gave up and used the internal wrappers as the structure turned into 140 bytes and we were not sure how to change alignment.

Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter, FilterIndex, Title, ButtonText, MultiSelect)
and Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFilename, FileFilter, FilterIndex, Title, ButtonText)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff834966.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel._application.getopenfilename.aspx

Needless to say we think all individuals with fairly heavy applications in Excel should start considering other options as maintaining future versions across multiple clients and platforms may just be... insane!

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get around this problem by setting the packing appropriately before including the header file. That way, for the purpose of this one function, we were using the 'default' 16 byte alignment, but did not have to change the packing alignment for the rest of our program:

```
#ifdef _WIN64
  #pragma pack( push )
  #pragma pack( 16 ) 
  #include "Commdlg.h"
  #pragma pack( pop )
#else
  #include "Commdlg.h"
#endif   // _WIN64
```